# laravel 8 include certain javascrip file into other js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack-mix

I have **two** files, one is my main js file called `app.js` and I have a file where I store all my js functions, called `functions.js`. As you can see on the image below.

[image]

But I want to include the `functions.js` file into the `app.js` file. So I googled on how to do it and this is what people said:

[image]

But my npm run dev says the file doesn't exist. But the path is correct. What am I doing wrong here, is there a other way to do it?

Comment: Try `require('./functions/functions.js')`

Comment: I did and it kinda worked! Npm run dev is successfully but my app.js doesn't recognize the functions I put in my function.js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just create the file wherever you want to create it, and then export some properties or methods, and then import them in your `app.js file`, or in whatever file you need. Something like this :

//new_file.js

```
export const jokes = function() {

        return ['funny', 'not really funny', 'boring']
}

export const  heading = 'some global heading to be reused.'
```

And in your app.js file :

```
import { jokes, heading } from 'new_file.js'//specify actual path here .

console.log(jokes) // ['funny', 'not really funny', 'boring']

console.log(heading)//some global heading to be reused.

This tutorial might be helpful too .

http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html
```

Comment: Wow that works actually, but isn't there an other way? Because now I have to import my functions everytime I make a new one.